# What is a toggle button and When can we use it?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, toggle

This seems to be primary Question. but i search it and i couldn't find direct answer.
What is toggle button and what is the difference between normal button and toggle button? When can we use it?

Comment: well the easiest one is. Its a checkbox having functionality of buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a button that has an on and off state.  You can see from the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.aspx#inheritanceContinued) that it inherits from the same class (ButtonBase) as the regular Button control.  And that both CheckBox and RadioButton inherit from it.

Answer (score 3):

Toggle button means if you need to button with two option like Play/Stop in a button at that time on first click it will be working as a play button and second time working as a stop button this is toggle button.